# How can I change the color of [INFO] in the console when running Tomcat in IntelliJ?

Tags: tomcat, logging, intellij-idea

I do not like the red color INFO, can I change it?

[image]

Comment: Colors are configured in "File | Settings | Editor | Color Scheme | Console Colors"

Comment: there is green color for info logging. And red for error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One of the solution would be to use [Grep Console](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7125-grep-console) plugin, which would be more flexible that IntelliJ's - you can even play some sounds on match.